# Automatic Differentiation - reverse accumulation of linear system solve

Tags: linear-solver, linear-system, automatic-differentiation

I am studying the reverse mode of
[automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).

The reverse mode of automatic differentiation allows the efficient computation of a the derivative of a single dependent variable $y$ with respect to as many independent variables $x_i$ as you want.
One assigns to each intermediate variable $v$ an adjoint variable $\bar{v}$ which is the derivative of a chosen dependent variable with respect to the subexpression $$\bar{v} \rightarrow \bar{v} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$

so the assignment $$y = v_1 \sin(v_2)$$ corresponds to the adjoint assignments

\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{v_1} &=& \bar{y} \sin(v_2) \\
\bar{v_2} &=& \bar{y} v_1 \cos(v_2)
\end{eqnarray}

where $\bar{y} = 1$ .

I am interested in the situation where you solve a linear system in the program:

$$Ax = b$$

where $y$ might be another function of $x$: $$y(x)$$

According to this [tutorial](http://www.scicomp.uni-kl.de/codi/d0/db5/TutorialA1.html) of the *CoDiPack* software, the corresponding adjoint statements are

\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{A} &=& - \lambda x^T \\
\bar{b} &=& \lambda \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $\lambda$ is the the solution of the adjoint equation 
$$A^T \lambda = \bar{x}$$

I found the same algorithm in several other documents, for example
[here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700004222) in section 7, *Iteration and equation solving*.

It is not clear to me how to arrive at these statements. 
I think the derivation must be similar as in the case where one wants to optimize $w(x)$ where $x$ is subject to the constraint $$Ax = b$$
See for example this [document](http://www.piercelab.caltech.edu/assets/papers/ftc00.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with $b=Ax$ the forward differentiation gives
$\dot b=\dot A x+A\dot x$, or, with $\dot y = \dot A x$:

$$\dot x = -A^{-1} \dot y + A^{-1} \dot b$$

Let's write this in terms of the local transformation Jacobian for the tangent linear variables $\left( \dot A, \dot y, \dot b, \dot x\right)$:

$$
\left[ 
 \begin{matrix}
  \dot A \\ \dot y\\ \dot b\\ \dot x\\
 \end{matrix}
\right] 
=
\left[ 
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -A^{-1} & A^{-1} & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
\left[ 
 \begin{matrix}
  \dot A \\ \dot y\\ \dot b\\ \dot x\\
 \end{matrix}
\right] 
$$

The adjoint operator is then the transpose matrix acting on the (local) adjoint variables $\left( \bar A, \bar y, \bar b, \bar x\right)$:

$$
\left[ 
 \begin{matrix}
  \bar A \\ \bar y\\ \bar b\\ \bar x\\
 \end{matrix}
\right] 
=
\left[ 
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & x^T & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -A^{-T} \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & A^{-T} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
\left[ 
 \begin{matrix}
  \bar A \\ \bar y\\ \bar b\\ \bar x\\
 \end{matrix}
\right], 
$$

or:

$$
\begin{align}
\bar y &= -A^{-T} \bar x \\
\bar A &\mathrel{+}= x^T \bar y \\
\bar b &\mathrel{+}= A^{-T} \bar x \\
\bar x &= 0.
\end{align} 
$$

Reference:

> Giering and Kaminski, [*Recipes for Adjoint Code Construction*](http://www.fastopt.com/papers/racc.pdf), ACM
>   TOMS, 1998

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this reference, reading it was quite helpful. I noted that you can actually do the same derivation without introducing the variable $\dot{y}$.

Comment: yes. the $\dot y$ keeps the explanation a bit simpler, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The identity connecting forward and reverse mode for $x=\text{solve}(A,b)$ is $$\bar x^⊤\dot x=\bar A(\dot A)+\bar b^⊤\dot b.$$ Where $\bar A$ is a linear functional on matrices which may be realized as the $trace(\bar A^⊤\dot A)$ which is related to the (Frobenius) scalar product for matrices $\langle X,Y\rangle=trace(X^⊤Y)=trace(XY^⊤)$, which is kind-of the euclidean scalar product as it is the sum over the element-wise product of $X$ and $Y$.

With $b=Ax$ the forward differentiation gives
$\dot b=\dot A x+A\dot x$, inserting you get 
$$
\bar x^⊤\dot x=\bar A(\dot A)+\bar b^⊤(\dot A x+A\dot x). \tag{1}
$$ 
As that has to be valid for all choices of $\dot A, \dot x$, one gets
\begin{align}
0&=trace(\bar A^⊤\dot A)+ \bar b^⊤\dot A x
\\
&=trace(\bar A^⊤\dot A)+ trace(\bar b^⊤\dot A x)
\\
&=trace(\bar A^⊤\dot A)+ trace(x\bar b^⊤\dot A)
\\
&=trace((\bar A+\bar bx^⊤)^⊤\dot A),
\\\text{and }~\bar b A\dot x&=\bar x\dot x \tag{2}
\end{align}
which implies 
$$
\bar b^⊤A=\bar x^⊤\iff \bar b=\text{solve}(A^⊤,\bar x),\tag3
\\
\bar A = -\bar bx^⊤.
\\
$$

Comment: Can you explain further how you arrive at the connecting identity? Is the right hand side after inserting the expression for $\dot{b}$ correct? Should it not only be $\bar{x}^T\dot{x}$?

Comment: You are correct, I started out with $b=Ax$ so that $A,x$ are the inputs and $b$ the output and did not correctly and completely change to $x=solve(A,b)$ where $A,b$ are the inputs and $x$ the output.

Comment: We have the identity $\bar{x}\dot{x} = \bar{y}\dot{y}$ that connects input /output of  a function in reverse and forward mode.  In order to be consistent, should we not choose an element-wise multiplication as the functional $\bar{A}(\cdot)$?

Comment: I did. $trace(\bar A^⊤\dot A)$ is the Euclidean scalar product for matrices.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't realize that it is actually the same. I still cannot see how you go from the statement where you inserted $\dot{b} = \dot{A}x + A\dot{x}$ to the next one. Is there a dot missing in $trace(\bar{A}^T{A}) \rightarrow trace(\bar{A}^T\dot{A})$?

Comment: Thanks, but it is still unclear how you go from (1) to (2). Is it only some algebra or is any additional information required to end up at (2)?

Comment: You can vary all components of $\dot x$ and $\dot A$ independently. Among other things you can set $\dot x=0$ or $\dot A=0$ which gives the separate conditions. Then consider that $trace(ABC)=trace(CAB)=trace(BCA)$ and also $trace(A)=trace(A^⊤)$.

Comment: OK, Now it makes sense to me, thank you for the clarifications!