# Reverse automatic differentiation and integration

Tags: reference-request, runge-kutta, automatic-differentiation

In *[Symplectic Runge-Kutta schemes for adjoint equations, automatic differentiation, optimal control and more](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04021)* Sanz Serna writes:

> It is well known that the reverse mode of differentiation implies
>   an integration of the adjoint equations.

Any source that shows the fact explicitly?
If I want to differentiate $ z = f(x, y) $ w.r.t. $(x,y)$, what would be the adjoint equation that should be integrated?

Comment: this is all explained on page 2 of that paper, see the paragraph that starts with _Section 3, the core of the paper (...)_. as for proofs re. adjoint consistency of RK discretizations, Andrea Walther's [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10589-006-0397-3) is a good place to start from.

Comment: @GoHokies They show how to get gradient w.r.t. the initial conditions, I don't get what the adjoint equation should be if there is no DE constraints and no cost function to minimize.

Comment: if you're looking at how to differentiate more general expressions $z = f(x,y)$ wrt $(x,y)$ then have a gander at [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/automatic-differentiation-reverse-accumulation-of-linear-system-solve/29421) (and the paper I refer to therein).